# How to create User Resgistration Page

Tags: wordpress

How do i create user resgistration form using Wordpress and point to my Database on Localhost. I tried to installed Login Plugin and activate it, but after that i dont now how it will work and connect with my local database.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin use:  [User registration & user profile – Profile Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/)